# Custom function in Select query Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.8

I a have Laravel DB query like this,

```js
$data = DB::table('jobs')
        ->select('id', 'customer_id', 'date','time')
        ->get();
```

I want to get the day of the date in the select query result. I'm using `Carbon::parse()->isoFormat('dddd');` to get the day of the date. I want to pass the date inside of `parse()` & get the relevant day. I want to be the query result as, ex: 1 , 2 , Monday, 11:30 AM. How can I process that code I mentioned to get the day inside of the select query. Is it possible? Help me with a solution. I'm using Laravel 5.8. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why are you trying to retrieve the date as day format, you can format the date field any where as a day or any other format using Carbon

Comment: by the way you can do it by defining an accessor, but I think that will suffer you in future as every time you retrieve the date it will be automatically converted to day as defined in accessor. see more about accessor here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 1):

**In your Job model**

```
public function getDateAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->isoFormat('dddd');
}
```

Write like

```
$data = Job::select('id', 'customer_id', 'date','time')->get();
```

Comment: I am new to laravel I'm using DB queries to do all the things. I want to retrieve the day of the date with SQL select results.   how can I process the date to get output with other query results

Answer (score 0):

**Note:custome function inside select query.This is possible with model only.without model its not working.**

```
$posts = TMCPost::select('tmc_posts.*', 'tmc_posts.id as encrypted_post_id')->get();
```

Inside Model

```
public function getEncryptedPostIdAttribute($value)
{
    return custom_function('encrypt',$value);
}
```

For More Brief Examples Follow
Source:
https://expertsuggestion.com/tutorial/laravel/how-to-use-custom-function-inside-select-query-laravel

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = DB::table('jobs')
        ->select('id', 'customer_id', \DB::raw("DAYNAME(date)"),'time')
        ->get();
```

DAYNAME function will return the name of the day at the specific date.
Here's [a link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_dayname)!.